# Repetition of raw dataset after clustering

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, nltk, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.08, max_features=200,
                                 min_df=0.02, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,3),tokenizer = tokenize_only_subject, analyzer='word')

tfidf_vectorizer.fit(enron_data["headers.Subject"])


tfidf_matrix_subject = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(enron_data["headers.Subject"])


print "\n\nshape of tfidf :\t",(tfidf_matrix_subject.shape)

terms_subject = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print "\n Feature's selected by machine from tdifd for Subject :\t",terms_subject

x =tfidf_matrix_subject.toarray()
#
#######################################################################################
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
distance = 1 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix_subject)

print "+++distance\t:",distance[:5]


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

num_clusters = 4

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)


print ":",km.fit_transform(tfidf_matrix_subject).shape


centroids = km.cluster_centers_
labels = km.labels_

print "Centroid is:\t",centroids
print "Labels is :\t",labels
n_clusters_ = km.labels_
print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n",n_clusters_
enron_cls = { 'enron_data_body': enron_data["body"],'enron_data_Subject': enron_data["headers.Subject"],'_id_':enron_data["_id"],"Date":enron_data["Date"],'cluster_': n_clusters_}

frame = pd.DataFrame(enron_cls, index = [n_clusters_] , columns = ['_id_','enron_data_body','enron_data_Subject','Date','cluster_'])

print frame.head()
frame.to_csv("errror.csv")
```

I need guidance or help over the clustering.
It is giving repeat values; for example, the fourth row of the raw dataset repeats as many times as the dataset count with cluster.
I want to cluster every row, not a repetition of the raw dataset.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, especially the repetition part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank Brian, it's great honor for me if i get your guidance and help.

Comment: looking for this output after kmean clustering over pandas dataframe
row  text    cluster
1 jd all well  0
2 come here  0
3 going to pub  0
4 working on data  1
5 show your work  1
6 very bad sound  0
7 Nice time with you 0
8 all is well  0
9 great work done  1
10 awesome pitcure  0

And I am getting this output, don't know where i am missing logic
row  text    cluster
1 jd all well  0
2 come here  1
3 jd all well  0
4 come here  1
5 jd all well  0
6 come here  1
7 jd all well  0
8 come here  1
9 jd all well  0
10 come here  1 -- this kind of repetition i am getting